# SdkManager class is not available in latest android SDK

Tags: java, android

Downloaded latest android Studio (`android-studio-bundle-162.3871768-windows`).
We were using `com.android.sdklib.SdkManager` class in our software but in latest Android Studio I'm not able to find the above mentioned class in any `jar` present inside the `tools\lib` folder.

Can anyone suggest what is the better alternative for this?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what you were using it for? Maybe you can try using the `sdkmanager` cli for the same

Comment: I want to get list of all the target installed by using getTargets() method present in SdkManager class.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get a list of all the targets installed for knowledge, then you can just simply run the SDK manager. But since you want to call the getTargets() method, it means you need it for other purposes. check up the documentation on the android studio web page to find out if it the class you are searching for exists and the location of its jar file.

Answer (score 0):

We can find the soure code of all the android classes in the below link.

https://javalibs.com/artifact/com.android.tools/sdklib?className=com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli&source

SdkManagerCli class have equivalent method  `listPackages()`which will list the packages.

We need to import sdklib-25.3.2.jar, repository-25.3.2.jar and common-25.3.2.jar to project.
Below is the working code for listing packages:-

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.TreeSet;
    import com.android.repository.Revision;
    import com.android.repository.api.ConsoleProgressIndicator;
    import com.android.repository.api.LocalPackage;
    import com.android.repository.api.ProgressIndicator;
    import com.android.repository.api.RepoManager;
    import com.android.repository.impl.meta.RepositoryPackages;
    import com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler;

        public class AndroidTesting {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                listPackages();
            }

           private static void listPackages() {
           AndroidSdkHandler mHandler = AndroidSdkHandler.getInstance(new 
            File("filePath")); //for eg:-sdk/platforms for API 
            ProgressIndicator progress = new ConsoleProgressIndicator();

            RepoManager mRepoManager = mHandler.getSdkManager(progress);
            mRepoManager.loadSynchronously(cacheExpirationMs, progress, 
            downloader, settings)(0, progress, null, null);

            RepositoryPackages packages = mRepoManager.getPackages();

            Collection<LocalPackage> locals = new TreeSet<LocalPackage>();
            Collection<LocalPackage> localObsoletes = new 
            TreeSet<LocalPackage>();
            for (LocalPackage local : packages.getLocalPackages().values()) {
                if (local.obsolete()) {
                    localObsoletes.add(local);
                } else {
                    locals.add(local);
                }
                Revision version = local.getVersion();

                System.out.println(local.getDisplayName() + " "
                    + local.getVersion() );
            }

        }
    }
```